# How to get a notification when any file on the system is opened by any application

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, hook

In my c# application [ Winform], I would like to get a notification when any of the application opens any file on my windows system.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: using `FileSystemWatcher` can help you **watch** it however you can't do anything like prevent it from happening... it's a pity.

Comment: A reliable solution involves writing a file system filter driver. The `FileSystemWatcher` does not generate a notification when a file is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do here. Does a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with filters for [LastAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) achieve what you need?

Comment: Except, the `LastAccess` event will not fire until the file handle is closed. This surely does not generate a notification when a file is opened. Plus, starting with Vista, the last access time (which the `FileSystemWatcher` uses) is not updated by default. Not to mention, that an application can call [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933.aspx) on a file with a magic value, and prevent any updates to the last access time, even if it is enabled in the OS.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks. this was very useful to debug the issues i was having.